# How can I leave a message in crashlog when I catch an exception?

Tags: iphone

I want to leave a message in crashlog when I catch an exception. Does NSLog() work?

Comment: yes, but why don't you just try it before asking?

Comment: I was not sure if NSLog() works when it's released on App Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write down in catch block:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [e reason]);
```

where e is the object of NSError class.

**Edited:**

```
@try {
    //Your Code
}
@catch (NSException * e) {
    NSLog(@"%@", [e reason]);
}
```

The above code find out any exception arising between your code.

Comment: Sorry reason is the method of NSException.

Comment: Please refer NSException class reference documentation.